# Tool to read Ansible debug module JSON output

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

When I run Ansible `debug` module and print out some variable, I get message that looks similar to JSON, but is not really JSON and can't be parsed into JSON directly. It looks like this:

```
ok: [zoo_01] => {
    "msg": "Hostvars {u'zoo_01': {u'module_setup': True, u'ansible_distribution_version'...
```

When I replace all of the following, it becomes parsable as JSON

```
u'    -> "
'     -> "
True  -> true
False -> false
None  -> null
```

Is there any tool that can parse it as JSON and show me it's nice structure? I would like something like this: https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor

Or maybe this format has a name?

Comment: Asking for a tool recommendation is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Python representation:

Use `to_json` filter to get JSON output. Or `var` instead of `msg`:

```
- debug:
    var: myvar

- debug:
    msg: "My JSON {{ myvar | to_json }}"
```